# how to fix " cannot import name 'interable' from 'colections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py) " in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04

After upgrade ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 showing this error

```
cannot import name 'interable' from 'colections'  (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Hi, everyone

I upgrade my ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 and I have a problem after doing this when my system starting up showing this error

```
cannot import name `interable` from `colections`  (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

[this is picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k12LM.png)

How to fix this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Iterable` class got removed from `collections` in Python 3.10 [see this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed), so you bumped your Python's version to 3.10 when updating Ubuntu.

You may try to revert your Python's version to 3.9 instead of 3.10, or may try to use `Iterable` from `collections.abc`.